# Select every other element from a vector

Tags: r, vector, seq

Let's say I had a vector:

`remove <- c(17, 18, 19, 20, 24, 25, 30, 31, 44, 45)`.

How do I select / extract every second value in the vector? Like so: `17, 19, 24, 30, 44`

I'm trying to use the `seq` function: `seq(remove, 2)` but it doesn't quite work.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: remove[seq(1, length(remove), by = 2)]

Comment: The structure for `seq` is `seq(start #, end #, interval)`. So saying `seq(remove,2)` is telling R: "start at all the numbers in remove, and count up by the default interval (which is 1) until you get to 2."

Answer (score 162, accepted):

```
remove[c(TRUE, FALSE)]
```

will do the trick.

---

*How it works?*

If logical vectors are used for indexing in R, their values are recycled if the index vector is shorter than the vector containing the values.

Here, the vector `remove` contains ten values. If the index vector `c(TRUE, FALSE)` is used, the actual command is: `remove[c(TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE)]`

Hence, all values with odd index numbers are selected.

Comment: Perfectly cromulent R!

Comment: I guess this works only if the vector has an even number of elements, though.

Answer (score 27):

```
remove[seq(1,length(remove),2)]
```

Answer (score 15):

Just another alternative:

```r
remove[seq_along(remove) %% 2 > 0]
# [1] 17 19 24 30 44
```