# Read observations in fixed width files spanning multiple lines in R

Tags: r, read.table

I am trying to read a dat file in R. The data is available [here](http://www.amstat.org/publications/jse/datasets/93cars.dat.txt).

The specification about the dataset is available [here](http://www.amstat.org/publications/jse/datasets/93cars.txt).

The first part of my problem is solved by using the `sep` option and providing information about where every column starts and providing the `na.strings="*"`. However, I do not know how to handle a single observation spanning more than 1 line.

In this data set, all the observations span 2 lines.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You actually need `read.fwf` for this.

Set up some sample data

```
    txt <- 'Acura         Integra        Small   12.9 15.9 18.8 25 31 0 1 4 1.8 140 6300
2890 1 13.2 5 177 102 68 37 26.5 11 2705 0
Acura         Legend         Midsize 29.2 33.9 38.7 18 25 2 1 6 3.2 200 5500
2335 1 18.0 5 195 115 71 38 30.0 15 3560 0
Audi          90             Compact 25.9 29.1 32.3 20 26 1 1 6 2.8 172 5500
2280 1 16.9 5 180 102 67 37 28.0 14 3375 0'
```

Read using read.fwf - pay attention to `widths` argument.  The `widths` should be a list of 2 integer vectors specifying element widths on multiple lines

```
DF <- read.fwf(textConnection(txt), 
               widths = list(
                 c(14, 15, 8, 5, 5, 5, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 4, 4, 4), 
                 c(5, 2, 5, 2, 4, 4, 3, 3, 5, 3, 5, 1)
               ), 
               header = FALSE)
```

Using `pander` package to pretty print the table since it has so many columns.

```
require(pander)
pandoc.table(DF)
## 
## ---------------------------------------------------
##  V1     V2      V3     V4   V5   V6   V7   V8   V9 
## ----- ------- ------- ---- ---- ---- ---- ---- ----
## Acura Integra  Small  12.9 15.9 18.8  25   31   0  
## 
## Acura Legend  Midsize 29.2 33.9 38.7  18   25   2  
## 
## Audi    90    Compact 25.9 29.1 32.3  20   26   1  
## ---------------------------------------------------
## 
## Table: Table continues below
## 
##  
## -----------------------------------------------
##  V10   V11   V12   V13   V14   V15   V16   V17 
## ----- ----- ----- ----- ----- ----- ----- -----
##   1     4    1.8   140  6300  2890    1   13.2 
## 
##   1     6    3.2   200  5500  2335    1   18.0 
## 
##   1     6    2.8   172  5500  2280    1   16.9 
## -----------------------------------------------
## 
## Table: Table continues below
## 
##  
## -----------------------------------------------
##  V18   V19   V20   V21   V22   V23   V24   V25 
## ----- ----- ----- ----- ----- ----- ----- -----
##   5    177   102   68    37   26.5   11   2705 
## 
##   5    195   115   71    38   30.0   15   3560 
## 
##   5    180   102   67    37   28.0   14   3375 
## -----------------------------------------------
## 
## Table: Table continues below
## 
##  
## -----
##  V26 
## -----
##   0  
## 
##   0  
## 
##   0  
## -----
##
```

Answer (score 9):

Here's a workaround:

```
link <- "http://www.amstat.org/publications/jse/datasets/93cars.dat.txt"
```

Read the raw lines:

```
rawlines <- readLines(file(link))
```

Convert to one text string:

```
lines <- paste(rawlines[c(TRUE, FALSE)], rawlines[c(FALSE, TRUE)], collapse = "\n")
```

The function `paste` is used to combine multiple strings. `rawlines[c(TRUE, FALSE)]` represents the odd lines, `rawlines[c(FALSE, TRUE)]` represents the even lines. (For details on how even and odd elements can be selected with boolean values, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13461829/r-how-to-list-every-other-element/13462110#13462110).) Both small lines are combined to one long line. Then, all long lines are combined into one single string with the argument `collapse = "\n"`. The lines are separated by line breaks (`\n`).

Read the new text with `read.table`:

```
dat <- read.table(text = lines, na.string = "*")
```

The result:

```
> head(dat)
     V1      V2      V3   V4   V5   V6 V7 V8 V9 V10 V11 V12 V13  V14  V15 V16  V17
1 Acura Integra   Small 12.9 15.9 18.8 25 31  0   1   4 1.8 140 6300 2890   1 13.2
2 Acura  Legend Midsize 29.2 33.9 38.7 18 25  2   1   6 3.2 200 5500 2335   1 18.0
3  Audi      90 Compact 25.9 29.1 32.3 20 26  1   1   6 2.8 172 5500 2280   1 16.9
4  Audi     100 Midsize 30.8 37.7 44.6 19 26  2   1   6 2.8 172 5500 2535   1 21.1
5   BMW    535i Midsize 23.7 30.0 36.2 22 30  1   0   4 3.5 208 5700 2545   1 21.1
6 Buick Century Midsize 14.2 15.7 17.3 22 31  1   1   4 2.2 110 5200 2565   0 16.4
  V18 V19 V20 V21 V22  V23 V24  V25 V26
1   5 177 102  68  37 26.5  11 2705   0
2   5 195 115  71  38 30.0  15 3560   0
3   5 180 102  67  37 28.0  14 3375   0
4   6 193 106  70  37 31.0  17 3405   0
5   4 186 109  69  39 27.0  13 3640   0
6   6 189 105  69  41 28.0  16 2880   1
```

Comment: Can you explain the line lines <- paste(rawlines[c(TRUE, FALSE)], rawlines[c(FALSE, TRUE)], collapse = "\n")   Also, is there a better way to do it. This works fine.

Comment: @ArkidMitra I added an explanation.

Comment: Works well for me. Is there a more standard way, was my next question?

Answer (score 2):

You can use option `fill=TRUE`

```
dat <- read.table('93cars.dat.txt',fill=TRUE)
               V1             V2      V3   V4    V5    V6 V7 V8   V9 V10  V11 V12 V13  V14
1           Acura        Integra   Small 12.9  15.9  18.8 25 31    0   1    4 1.8 140 6300
2            2890              1    13.2  5.0 177.0 102.0 68 37 26.5  11 2705 0.0  NA   NA
3           Acura         Legend Midsize 29.2  33.9  38.7 18 25    2   1    6 3.2 200 5500
4            2335              1    18.0  5.0 195.0 115.0 71 38 30.0  15 3560 0.0  NA   NA
5            Audi             90 Compact 25.9  29.1  32.3 20 26    1   1    6 2.8 172 5500
```

Then if you want to get each line in a seprated data.frame ; I mean lines line1,line3,.. in a data.frame and line2,line4,.. in another data.frame you can do this :

```
dat.even <- dat[c(FALSE,TRUE),]
dat.odd  <- dat[c(TRUE,FALSE),]
```