# read txt file with two lines for each case; with R

Tags: r, rstudio

how to read from R a .txt file with two lines for each case. For example a file like [ http://www.amstat.org/publications/jse/datasets/93cars.dat.txt ]
Please help.
CL

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the simplest way I can think of.  And you should note that your URL link in the question includes the square bracket, which might slow folks down.

```
u <- url("http://www.amstat.org/publications/jse/datasets/93cars.dat.txt")

d <- readLines(u)

s <- paste(d[seq(1,length(d),2)], d[seq(2,length(d),2)])

data <- read.table(header=F, stringsAsFactors=F, text=s)
```

Comment: Hi, Forrest  I appreciate your help. Sorry about the ].

Answer (score 0):

There are many other ways to do this, and indeed this question is an exact duplicate of the question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15596679/read-observations-in-fixed-width-files-spanning-multiple-lines-in-r) (same question, same data), which has an answer using `read.fwf` which requires you to know the fixed-width of each field. This can be automated but perhaps cumbersome.

The most scalable way, at least on POSIX machines is to use command line tools like `awk` to do the pre-processing efficiently and quickly for you. Here is an example using `awk` that reads the file in two parts (alternate rows) and `cbind`s them together.

```
download.file("http://www.amstat.org/publications/jse/datasets/93cars.dat.txt", 
                             destfile = "Data/93cars.txt")
firstPart = pipe(description = "awk 'NR%2==0' < Data/93cars.txt")
secondPart = pipe(description = "awk 'NR%2 != 0' < Data/93cars.txt")
dfCars = cbind(read.table(firstPart), read.table(secondPart))
```