tsv file columns not importing properly
Apologies if this is a simple question, but I've been having issues with reading a tsv file into RStudio. Because the entries in the second column tend to be two-word entries, the space breaks the row into a new line, resulting in an incorrectly parsed file. please see the code and result below

neuro_subclusters <- read.delim(url("https://shendure-web.gs.washington.edu/content/members/DEAP_website/public/RNA/update/neuronal_fine_scale_annotations/neuronal_subcluster_annotations.txt"), col_names = TRUE)

result: (https://i.sstatic.net/9Q67AVkK.png)
Any help would be appreciated, as this has been driving me insane! thank you
I have tried reformatting the file to "detect" likely line breaks by for looping through each row, but I haven't been able to do it successfully. Basically I am open to any ideas.

This ideas might help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15596679/read-observations-in-fixed-width-files-spanning-multiple-lines-in-r

Another option to look into is the fread function from the data.table library. If you use sep = "\t", and your two word column uses spaces rather than tabs, it should be okay.
If you're still getting stuck, adding a minimal reproducible example would help.

It seems that only multi-word annotations are split with newlines, so there are actually some complete lines.
We could focus on detecting & replacing newlines in annotations, a good candidate for such check would be a regex that looks for newlines that are followed by not-tab-characters<tab><digits><newline>, by replacing those matches we should end up with complete tsv lines (SO replaces tabs with spaces, so tsv_sample here is not exactly reproducible):
library(readr)
library(stringr)

tsv_sample <- 
"cell_name  annotation  seurat_clusters
16_18_exp1_idx1AGTCCGCTGC_idx2CGAAGGACGA.TAGAGAGTATGCTCTCGCCT   Neural
progenitors 1
16_18_exp1_idx1GCTTGAAGAG_idx2TCGTAGGCTT.TATCCAGGTGATGATCGTA    Ventral
midline 9
16_18_exp10_idx1GAGCGCGATG_idx2CTCGTCTAGG.TACTTGCGTCATTATTACC   Head epid.
/muscle 4
12_14_exp1_idx1AGTCCGCTGC_idx2CCAGGTCTAC.GGAGGTTCTATGCAATATG    Oenocytes   18
"
str_view(tsv_sample)
#> [1] │ cell_name{\t}annotation{\t}seurat_clusters
#>     │ 16_18_exp1_idx1AGTCCGCTGC_idx2CGAAGGACGA.TAGAGAGTATGCTCTCGCCT{\t}Neural
#>     │ progenitors{\t}1
#>     │ 16_18_exp1_idx1GCTTGAAGAG_idx2TCGTAGGCTT.TATCCAGGTGATGATCGTA{\t}Ventral
#>     │ midline{\t}9
#>     │ 16_18_exp10_idx1GAGCGCGATG_idx2CTCGTCTAGG.TACTTGCGTCATTATTACC{\t}Head epid.
#>     │ /muscle{\t}4
#>     │ 12_14_exp1_idx1AGTCCGCTGC_idx2CCAGGTCTAC.GGAGGTTCTATGCAATATG{\t}Oenocytes{\t}18
#>     │

# regular expression with positive look-ahead, 
# replace newlines that are followed by not-tab-characters\t\digits
str_replace_all(tsv_sample, regex("\\n(?=[^\\t]+\\t\\d+\\n)", multiline = TRUE), " ") |> 
  str_view()
#> [1] │ cell_name{\t}annotation{\t}seurat_clusters
#>     │ 16_18_exp1_idx1AGTCCGCTGC_idx2CGAAGGACGA.TAGAGAGTATGCTCTCGCCT{\t}Neural progenitors{\t}1
#>     │ 16_18_exp1_idx1GCTTGAAGAG_idx2TCGTAGGCTT.TATCCAGGTGATGATCGTA{\t}Ventral midline{\t}9
#>     │ 16_18_exp10_idx1GAGCGCGATG_idx2CTCGTCTAGG.TACTTGCGTCATTATTACC{\t}Head epid. /muscle{\t}4
#>     │ 12_14_exp1_idx1AGTCCGCTGC_idx2CCAGGTCTAC.GGAGGTTCTATGCAATATG{\t}Oenocytes{\t}18
#>     │
Stackoverflow removes tabs, for reproducible `tsv_sample` you probably need to copy it from the source.


Testing with complete file:
tsv <- "https://shendure-web.gs.washington.edu/content/members/DEAP_website/public/RNA/update/neuronal_fine_scale_annotations/neuronal_subcluster_annotations.txt"
read_file(tsv) |> 
  str_replace_all(regex("\\n(?=[^\\t]+\\t\\d+\\n)", multiline = TRUE), " ") |> 
  read_tsv() 
#> Rows: 59012 Columns: 3
#> ── Column specification ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
#> Delimiter: "\t"
#> chr (2): cell_name, annotation
#> dbl (1): seurat_clusters
#> 
#> ℹ Use `spec()` to retrieve the full column specification for this data.
#> ℹ Specify the column types or set `show_col_types = FALSE` to quiet this message.
#> # A tibble: 59,012 × 3
#>    cell_name                                          annotation seurat_clusters
#>    <chr>                                              <chr>                <dbl>
#>  1 16_18_exp1_idx1AGTCCGCTGC_idx2CGAAGGACGA.TAGAGAGT… Neural pr…               1
#>  2 16_18_exp1_idx1GCTTGAAGAG_idx2TCGTAGGCTT.TATCCAGG… Ventral m…               9
#>  3 16_18_exp10_idx1GTAGCAGCTA_idx2AGTCCGCGGA.TCCAATA… Neural pr…              11
#>  4 16_18_exp10_idx1TAGTAAGCCG_idx2TTAGATTCCG.TCCTCGA… Sensory p…               6
#>  5 16_18_exp10_idx1TATTAGACTT_idx2CGACTACCAA.GGTTCGA… Neural pr…              11
#>  6 16_18_exp3_idx1AGACCATATC_idx2CGATCATTAC.TAAGACCG… Sensory p…              14
#>  7 16_18_exp3_idx1ATTATGCAAG_idx2TGATAGAACG.TGCGTAGT… Sensory p…               6
#>  8 16_18_exp1_idx1GCGCGTTCAT_idx2CCGTCGGAGG.GGCGCATT… Immature …               7
#>  9 16_18_exp1_idx1GTAGCAGCTA_idx2GTCGCTCAGT.GCAACGTT… Immature …               8
#> 10 16_18_exp1_idx1GTAGGCTGCA_idx2CGAGCTGCCA.CGAGATGC… Immature …               7
#> # ℹ 59,002 more rows

Created on 2024-11-05 with reprex v2.1.1
