# R looping through multiple dataframes in a list

Tags: r, dataframe

Attempting to calculate differences between every two values in a row then sum the total differences for each dataframe in a list. I know for/while loops in R absolutely suck. I had this working before, but I've broken it. Can someone suggest how to optimize this using an alternative in the apply family? Current code:

```
 for (i in 1:length(refdata)) { #for each dataframe in a list
    refdif <- as.data.frame(matrix(0, ncol = 1, nrow = nrow(refdata[[i]])))
    refdif1 <- c()
    for (z in 1:ncol(refdata[[i]])) { #for each column in a dataframe
        for(x in 1:nrow(refdata[[i]])) { #for each row in a dataframe
            refdif <- (refdata[[i]][x,z] - refdata[[i]][x,z+1]) #difference of first value + the enxt
            refdif1[x,1] <- (refdif1[x,1] + refidf) #sum of latest difference
        }
    }
    print(refdif1) #where I can conduct tests on each individual dataframe with a column of sums of differences
}
```

example data:
list 1 refdata[[1]]

```
$`1`
     var1 var2 var3 var4 
  1   1     2    3    4
  2   5     6    7    8

$`2`
     var1 var2 var3 var4 
  1   1     2    3    4
  2   5     6    7    8
```

var 1 + 2 has the difference calculated, var 3 and 4 has the difference calculated, then each difference is summed together and placed in a new dataframe in a single column. (5-6) + (7-8), (1-2) + (3-4), etc etc:

```
$`1`
     dif  
  1   -2
  2   -2


$`2`
     dif  
  1   -2
  2   -2
```

Comment: this would strongly benefit from a sample data list.

Comment: @MichaelChirico updated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do it (per unlisted dataframe) could be by using logical vectors for indexing - their values are [recycled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13461829/r-how-to-list-every-other-element) - that way calculating the difference between every other column and finally summing the resulting df row-wise.

```
refdata1<-rowSums(refdata[c(T,F)]-refdata[c(F,T)])
```

**Edit**

Exact output can be obtained by

```
lapply(refdata, function(df){ data.frame(dif=rowSums(df[c(T,F)]-df[c(F,T)])) })
```

thx [Heroka](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5020008/heroka)

Comment: Are you sure you need colSums?

Comment: The exact output could be obtained by `lapply(refdata, function(df){
  data.frame(dif=rowSums(df[c(T,F)]-df[c(F,T)]))
})`

Comment: yes :) you mind if I put it into the answer as an update?

Comment: No, that's why I put it in a comment (and deleted my answer, as yours is so much more elegant)

Comment: Thanks guys. Works well.

Comment: @Heroka When working with two lists is it possible to iterate over both with mapply to do a comparison between dataframes at the same iteration? Each list has the same number of dataframes and each correlates to the other. I am trying this: mapply(refdata1, refdata2, function(x,y) { x(dif=rowSums(df[c(T,F)]-df[c(F,T)])); y(dif=rowSums(df[c(T,F)]-df[c(F,T)])) })

Comment: @JeffLynch please consider making a new question, and not changing your old one/asking a new one in the comments.

Answer (score 1):

```
# Create test data
x <- rbind(1:4, 5:8)
refdata <- list(x,x)

# Calculate results (all elements should have an even number of columns)
lapply(refdata,  FUN = function(x) x %*% rep_len(c(1, -1), NCOL(x)))
```