# SLICING operation with R

Tags: python, r

`_range=10`

`ret[_range:] = ret[_range:] - ret[:-_range]`

here ret is NumpyArray in python

now please suggest me , how can i do this with R

Comment: Not everybody knows Python so please try explaining what you are trying to do by giving an example and show expected output for the same/

Comment: @RonakShah i am done with that problem ,can you tell me how to do `[::2]` this operation in R

Comment: Again, I don't know what `[::2]` does in Python so please try to explain clearly with an example.

Comment: @RonakShah if `list=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8] ` after this [::2] , we get `output=[1,3,5,7]` this is what it does

Comment: This is the answer to `[::2]` in R https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13461829/select-every-other-element-from-a-vector

Answer (score 2, accepted):

simple way to do this

Try this

`tail(ret,-range ) - head(ret,-range )`

maybe you will find alternet way as well