# How to convert the for-loop from Python to R?

Tags: python, r, for-loop

I try to convert [the @JonathanAllan's Python code](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/92868/is-it-possible-to-put-the-numbers-into-circles) to R code.
My attempt is below:

```
library(e1071) # permutations

n <- 24
sideSum <- 42

iterSolutions <- function(sideSum, n){

Q = c(list(seq(1, n)))
for(A in combn(seq(1, n), 4))
{
  if (sum(A) != sideSum) { next }
  Q1 = setdiff(Q, A)
# for a, d, b, c in list(permutations(A))[::2]:
  tmp = permutations(A)
  for ( c(a, d, b, c) in tmp[seq(1, length(tmp), by=2)]){
    for (B in combn(Q1, 3)){
         if (a + sum(B) != sideSum) { next }
         Q2 = setdiff(Q1, B)
    } # for B
    } # for a, b, d, c
} # for A
#......
return c(a, b, d, c)

} # function
```

**Question.** How to re-write the for-loop
`for a, d, b, c in list(permutations(A))[::2]:` in R?

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13461829/select-every-other-element-from-a-vector

Comment: what is `a, d, b, c`? Is it the individual value of columns from `permutations(A)` ?

Comment: @RonakShah, it is the individual value

Comment: Since the list is a list of tuples, you would use indices in R eg `for (i in x){a <- i[1];d<-i[2];b <-i[3]...}` then you continue.