# How to use 'seq' function in R to get odd and even numbers?

Tags: r

This is an example. Let's assume we have big dataset:

```
Numbers <- c(45, 67, 89, 45, 34, 65, 90, 99, 83, 88)
```

I want to use seq function to get 1) even numbers 2) odd numbers

Comment: You mean to separate those numbers into even and odd? I'm not sure what `seq` would do for you. `Numbers %% 2 == 0` tells you whether a number is even (if this returns true) or odd (if returns false)

Comment: Odd numbers - like their position: 45, 89, 34, 90, 83

Comment: Even numbers - again their even position, 67, 45, 65, 99, 88

Comment: Numbers[c(TRUE, FALSE)] #Odd positioned numbers
Numbers[c(FALSE, TRUE)] #Even positioned numbers

Comment: The fact that you want to extract numbers by the evenness/oddness of their *index*, not their own value, wasn't at all clear from the question. In that case, do the same modulo calculation I showed on the index

Comment: Now, I just want to use seq to find these numbers. I hope it clarifies

Comment: why do you want to use `seq` ?

Comment: just saw: already answered: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13461829/select-every-other-element-from-a-vector

Answer (score 1):

If you want to / have to use `seq`, you can do:

```r
# Get numbers at odd indices (1, 3, 5, ...)
Numbers[seq(from = 1, to = length(Numbers), by = 2)]
#> [1] 45 89 34 90 83

# Get numbers at even indices (2, 4, 6, ...)
Numbers[seq(from = 2, to = length(Numbers), by = 2)]
#> [1] 67 45 65 99 88
```