# Converting a one-dimensional array

Tags: r

> transform a one-dimensional array consisting of n integer elements in
> such a way that the first half contains elements in odd positions, and
> the second half contains elements in even positions

Source array: (1, 6, 2, 5, 4)

After process i need this: (1, 2, 4, 6, 5)

Comment: Please show your attempts.

Comment: @G.Grothendieck, I would like to, but in fact I was only trying to rewrite the code from C +, unfortunately I don’t have an environment at hand

Comment: relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13461829/select-every-other-element-from-a-vector

Comment: `c(x[c(TRUE, FALSE)], x[c(FALSE, TRUE)])` should solve your issue

Answer (score -1):

Try to use the `sort()` function:

Something like this:

```
# create a linear array
arr <- c(9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1)
 
# use of sort function to sort array
# by default it is sorted in increasing order
sort(arr)

# Output: [1] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
```

And take a look at this [tutorial](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/sorting-of-arrays-in-r-programming/#:%7E:text=sort()%20function%20in%20R,parameter%20to%20the%20sort%20function.).