# How would I go about splitting a string of values that contains both x and y coordinates into two subsets using a pattern?

Tags: string, split, stringr

I am trying to figure out the best way to split a string of values.. Each string is a series of xy pixel coordinates that ultimately form a polygon. But I can't seem to find a solution where I can split the string into two subsets.. one with all the x coordinates and one with all the y coordinates for each polygon.

This is the current format:

| polygonID | Points |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | [x1,y1,x2,y2,x3,y3...] |
| 2 | [x1,y1,x2,y2,x3,y3...] |

Example of values:
[[1057.97, 338.98, 1069.53, 322.73,..........]]
[[   x1  ,   y1,       x2  ,   y2,...........]]

So you can see the first two values create an xy pair, and therefore I would need to pull the first x and then every other value after to subset all x coordinate values.. and do the same for all y coordinates to create two columns of points.

(side note: the length of coordinate points per polygon varies)

Ultimately what I want is two lists then which would look like this:

| polygonID | X_coords | Y_coords |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | [x1,x2,x3,...] | [y1,y2,y3,...] |
| 2 | [x1,x2,x3,...] | [y1,y2,y3,...] |

I have looked at options with stringr and dplyr, but I have not found a good solution (I also don't have any code worked out just yet as I am trying to gain any insight first). Any and all help is appreciated. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so I'm by no means an expert and I might be complicating things but at least I think I have a working answer. If I understand correctly, the column "Points" of your data-frame (which I will call `df`) is a character column.

Then:

```
df %>%
mutate(Points = strsplit(gsub("\\[|\\]","",Points), ","),
      xcoord = paste0("[", sapply(map(Points, ~.x[c(TRUE, FALSE)]), paste, collapse = ","),"]" ),
      ycoord = paste0("[", sapply(map(Points, ~.x[c(FALSE, TRUE)]), paste, collapse = ","),"]" )) %>%
select(-Points)
```

I start by removing the brackets in your column "Points" with `gsub()`, then split the strings with `strsplit()`. If you want to keep the Points column, just rename that result.

Then, in order:

1. I select every other element in Points by mapping and recycling the logical vector `c(TRUE, FALSE)` (inspired from this post: [Select every other element from a vector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13461829/select-every-other-element-from-a-vector))
2. I use `sapply` to paste together the list from point 1 with "," as a separator.
3. I'm not sure if you need the brackets but I use `paste0` to paste brackets before and after the result from point 2.
4. I use `select()` to remove the Points column (if not needed anymore).

Comment: Great! Happy it worked :)
If anyone else has a less convoluted way of doing it i'd be happy to see it!